# How to save an Email attachment as an Email message?

Tags: php

I am pretty new when it comes to handling emails in php.

Basically I need to read a pop3 mailbox and save the messages to a database and the attachments to a folder. Then mail that same mail (slightly altered) back to another email recipient.

I thought I got this all working, then I realized when the attachment is another mail message I only receive the body as text (after base64_decode).

Is it possible to save an attached email to a file and then send it as attachment in another message?

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is some code to put it into perspective :

```
// This is the IMAP connection: imap_open("{"."$host:$port/pop3$ssl"."}$folder",$user,$pass,OP_SILENT);
$mailConnection = $this->Maildata->mail_login($host,$port,$user,$pass,$folder,$ssl);

// This retrieves the list of mails in the current folder
$messageList = $this->Maildata->mail_list($mailConnection,$message);
foreach ($messageList as $messageId => $messageListData) {

    // This reads the mail object into an array
    $mailMessage = $this->Maildata->mail_mime_to_array($mailConnection,$messageId,true);

    // This loops through each mail
    foreach ($mailMessage as $tmpId => $tmpData) {
        // Excluded save to database since it is unrelated

        // This checks if item is an attachment and saves it.
        if (isset($tmpData['is_attachment']) && $tmpData['is_attachment'] === true) {
            $tmpName = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now'));
            $this->Maildata->mail_attachment_save($tmpData['data'], $tmpName .$tmpData['name']);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. This all works, but `imap_fetchbody($mailConnection , $messageId, $prefix);` doesn't seem to send all the data I need.

Comment: Please show us your code. It is incorrect to say that it is "another message", what MIME parser are you using?

Comment: This may help: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php  Even though it says 'IMAP' I believe it can work with POP as well.

Comment: @DaveRandom I am using IMAP to connect to the mail box. I will add some code, but I don't believe it will help.

Comment: @Nightwolf Which library/functions are you using to do this?

Comment: @DaveRandom the code I use is the only comment on [http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.imap.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.imap.php). But there is simple flaws in the code that I needed to correct.

Comment: @Nightwolf OK, and how have you tried to implement it? What is your code that utilises those functions?

Comment: @DaveRandom I used `imap_fetchbody($mailConnection , $messageId, $prefix);` with all the prefixes I can think of. I think it might be that this is why I don't get all the data I need. But lets say for a moment I do have the data in a variable or object, how would I save it to resend later as an attachment?

Comment: @DaveRandom I finally realized that I do have all of the attached message's data, but this is where my question comes into play:
Is it possible to save an attached email to a file and then send it as attachment in another message?

Comment: @Nightwolf You `do have all of the attached message's data` - where is it? In a variable?

Comment: @DaveRandom In this specific case the '2' part of Imap fetchbody has the data and then I can just assign it to a variable:`$attachedMail = imap_fetchbody($mailConnection, $messageId, '2')`. I see that I can save this as a file  

    imap_savebody($mailConnection, $file, $messageId, '2');

 with a .eml extension and the file will work in Windows live mail. But there is not an extension that allows outlook to read the attachment properly. I tried no extension as well, with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You can save attached mail messages as a file, but it will not be in a format that Microsoft Office Outlook will understand. Interestingly enough if you save the file as a .eml then windows live mail will handle the message perfectly.

No webmail service handles attached mail items as outlook and windlows live mail does and gmail ignores them completely.